# 433 MHz Antenna Layout

Tags: rf, antenna, 433mhz

I'm trying to build a remote control unit and want to 'remote' the antenna from the 433 MHz Tx unit. I'd appreciate some feedback before I order as my antenna/RF theory is sketchy and I want to know if there will be any effects.

My concept so far is this:

The 433 MHz unit sits on top of the PCB, attached by header pins at four points (VCC, Data, Gnd and Antenna). The Antenna trace goes a short distance through the VCC plane and above a GND plane. It then connects to a brass SMA and 1/4 wavelength antenna.

- RF Tx Module:
  http://www.energiazero.org/arduino_sensori/Complete%20Guide%20for%20RF%20433MHz%20Transmitter.pdf
- SMA Connector:
  https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/coaxial-connectors/8861061/
- 433 MHz Antenna: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/rfid-antennas/7620030/

It's the same schematic as I used to prototype something which worked before. Only the layout is new. Image attached.

[image]

Comment: Your layout will work as is, but technically speaking the trace to the antenna should be a 50 ohm impedance microstrip line. You can find online calculators to determine the trace width for 50 ohms based on your pcb thickness and dielectric constant.

Comment: Connecting an antenna signal with some through-hole connector board-to-board is very questionable. Impedance matching and signal loss will be issues, but also a the 90 degree bend, as well as the through-hole pin on the bottom of the board acting as a second antenna. The Arduino trash module you linked is unlikely to be legal in any country around the world anyhow, so the antenna is the least of your concerns. How do you plan to pass EN/ETSI 300 220?

Comment: (Also a 1/4 wavelength stub antenna requires a big ground plane to work. You can't just connect that one directly to your PCB unless your PCB is huge.)

Comment: Hi @Lundin, thanks for your comments. I believe in the UK it's a License Exempt Short Range Device and fully legal as long as it's used within design parameters. As for the standard you reference, this is hobby work and not commercial.

Can you offer any suggestions on an alternate solution? I'm trying to make a remote control system which is more refined than a bodged prototype. The existing (and working) device simply uses a 17cm monopole copper wire coming directly from the ANT connection of the Tx module.

Comment: License free doesn't mean "anything goes". It means that you don't have to pay rent to use the band. But your device must conform to EN/ETSI 300 220 or you are not allowed to use it. Generally SRDs on 433MHz are limited to 1mW 10% duty cycle. I think the UK specifically got some more lenient rules than EU (and now there's Brexit too), I can't be bothered to look it up. But I'm very certain that 300 220 still applies.

Comment: Suggestions for alternatives would be any radio that isn't some Arduino/Ebary/Ali Baba scam for a few dollars. In practice, there's so much traffic on this band that you must use narrowband FSK or anyone (like some radio amateur or another illegal hobbyist) will easily jam you out. ASK, OOK and simplistic modulations like that simply aren't feasible.

Comment: @Lundin thanks. Perhaps naively I assume that if it's for sale it's legal if used, like I say, within design parameters. I know that I'm meeting a 10% duty cycle. Nonetheless I'm starting to think that it's easier to get a board with an integrated SMA anyway rather than design my own. I've got enough on my hands with fitting motors to a loft ladder!

Comment: @Josh Well, it _might_ pass radio testing but I doubt it. And no matter, you might want an end product that can actually be used inside cities. And yeah it is naive to think you can buy any form of quality (radio) product for just a few dollars.